# Im implementing code for Reset form field please help me in regard this

Tags: android

My code is:

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

OnClickListener onclick1 = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setText("");
        }
    };
    button1.setOnClickListener(onclick1);
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Please explain what the code does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: im not reset field sir..

Comment: Error is showing on emulator application has stopped unexpectedly..

Comment: @Nareshbabu : its Because you declared  button1.setOnClickListener(onclick1);below. Declare it above or check my answer.

Comment: @Nareshbabu where u have define method in on create or outside of oncreate

Comment: first get some understanding of java and inner classes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        spinner.setSelection(0); //if the field is spinner
        editText.setText("");  //if the field is EditText
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific about your question. But if you want to just clear the `EditText` on Button click then u hv to do this :

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

et.setText("");


            }
        });
```